# How to control Chrome in a network environment

Tags: chrome

Using Server 2003 and XP clients:
Does anyone know of an adm file to control Chrome on a network. I have one for installation and update but that's it.
Alternatively, does anyone know of any registry hacks to lock it down. I was thinking of running a script at log in to update the registry and control things that way.
I work in a school so preventing users (kids) from making changes is essential.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference:

- Policy templates are available at http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=187945
- Lots of useful tips at http://www.chromium.org/administrators
- Feel free to file bugs/feature requests at the chromium bug tracker using the Enterprise Issue template

Answer (score 1):

There's one here.

[Chrome ADM](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates)

Comment: There's a page with, basically, the same content being hosted on a "google.com" page now, too: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=187945